# How to play sound iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, ios-simulator

I am new to IOS programming and was trying to find an easy way to play a sound out xcode to the simulator. I am using macincloud and they said they are having trouble getting the sound from xcode through rdp. I have written a simple app that streams music from my server but no sound is coming out. I need to know if it my code not working or macinclouds setup that is not working. So is there an easy way of making xcode make any sound to test.

Thanks.

Comment: Open the simulator -> tap on Safari -> navigate to youtube.com -> play any video.

Comment: Thanks @beyowolf that showed it was a problem on their end